# add middleware to all routes but a few

Tags: node.js, express

how can I add middleware to all possible routes except for these that match a given expression?

I know how to add a middleware to ones that match an expression:

```
app.all('/test/*', requireLogin);
```

but I want to require login in all routes except for a few that have a specific prefix in their paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using express 3.x series you are out of luck here. You need to hack the middle ware  to to check the the path.

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
   if(canRouteSkipLogin(req.path)
        next();
   else{
       //Do the auth logic 
   }

});

canRouteSkipLogin = function(path){
 //logic to find the path which can skip login
}
```

While in express 4.0 you can do it much easier way.

```
 var authRoutes = express.Router();
 var nonAuthRoutes = express.Router();

authRoutes.use(function(req, res, next) {
    //Do Auth Logic here
});
```

Hope this explains.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to do this is to just explicitly code for it with a guard clause in the middleware itself. So the middleware always gets called, it checks `req.path` against the bypass regex, and if so, just calls `next()` immediately and returns. This is the pattern used by things like the [expressjs body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/74aa3e1120bcfb588b6573c5bcafdf1fddcfb5cb/index.js#L71) (via the type-is module) to no-op themselves based on checking that a given request doesn't require them to do anything.