# Run express middleware for all routes except that are starting with /api?

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I have an Express middleware that renders React on the server like so, placed at the end, after all other routes:

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
  Router.run(routes, req.path, function(Handler) {
    var markup = React.renderToString(<Handler />);
    res.send(swig.renderFile('views/index.html', { html: markup }));
  });
});
```

Since no route is specified this middleware will execute for all requests. I would like to exclude all `/api` routes from it. The problem is even if I create all API routes before this middleware, there is always a possibility for this middleware to be executed on `/api/nonexistantendpoint` path.

To be more precise, I am looking for a regex that would make this middleware execute for all paths except any path starting with `/api`.

Thanks!

---

I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921658/use-specific-middleware-in-express-for-all-paths-except-a-specific-one) SO post but couldn't find anything useful to me.

And [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313016/catch-all-route-except-for-login) contains a lot of workarounds which is also not what I am looking for.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622538/add-middleware-to-all-routes-but-a-few) post asks you to conditionally check for URL inside the middleware.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.use(/^\/(?!api).*/, function(req, res) {
  Router.run(routes, req.path, function(Handler) {
    var markup = React.renderToString(<Handler />);
    res.send(swig.renderFile('views/index.html', { html: markup }));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handle non existent api routes.
I have `api` folder that contains all my api route, ideally each in their own js file and api/index.js requires all these routes like this

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.use(require('./users'));
router.use(require('./it'));
//other routes.js
```

then at the end in my `api/index.js` I have this

```
router.use('/*', function(req, res) { //this will reject any /api/nonexistant routes
  res.send(500).end();
});
```

In my server js I include my api routes first

```
app.use('/api', require('./api'));
app.use(function(req, res) {
  console.log('dosomething');
  res.send('Hello something').end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I had the exact same use case as Sahat, here's the syntax I used for configuring two routes to handle `/api` matches and misses in Express.js:

```
// /api/* Matches
app.get( '^/api/:params*', function( req, res, next ) {
    res.send( "Matches an /api/ route." );
} );

// /api/* Misses
app.get( /^((?!\/api\/).)*$/, function( req, res, next ) {
    res.send( "NOT an /api/ route." );
} );
```

This assumes that all of your API routes follow a pattern of `/api/*`.